# Related Rates Question: If a snowball melts so that its surface area decreases at a rate of $3~\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{min}}$

Tags: calculus

If a snowball melts so that its surface area decreases at a rate of $3~\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{min}}$, find the rate at which the diameter decreases when the diameter is $8$ cm.

My answer is wrong. Can some one help me solve?

Given: The rate of decrease of the surface area is $3~\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{min}}$. I f we let $t$ be time in (in minutes) and $s$ be the surface area (in cm$^2$), then we are given that $\frac{ds}{dt} = -3~\text{cm}^3$

Unknown: The rate of decrease of the diameter when the diameter is $8$ cm

If we let $x$ be the diameter, then we want to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ when $x = 8$ cm. If the radius is $r$ and the diameter is $x = 2r$ then $r = \frac{1}{2}x$ and $S = 4\pi r^2$, $x=2r$, then $r=\frac{1}{2}x$
$S=\pi x^2 =-\frac{3}{2}\pi 8$

My answer is wrong. Can some one help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that the surface area formula is:

$$SA = 4\pi r^2$$

If we take the derivative with respect with time, we get:

$$\frac{dSA}{dt} = 8\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}$$

Now, from the problem we are given that $\frac{dSA}{dt} = -3$, and $r = 4$

Now we can find $\frac{dr}{dt}$:

$$ 32\pi \frac{dr}{dt} = -3,\ \frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{3}{32\pi}$$

Now, we can also make the relation that:

$$d = 2r,\ \frac{dd}{dt} = 2\frac{dr}{dt} = 2*\left(-\frac{3}{32\pi}\right) = -\frac{6}{32\pi}$$

Therefore our diameter decreases at a rate of $\frac{6}{32\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is asking about the diameter rather than the radius, you can also deal directly with the diameter from the beginning and save some work later.  This is based on the fact that $r=\frac{d}{2}$ (radius is always half the diameter).

$$SA=4 \pi r^2$$
$$SA=4 \pi \bigg( \frac{d}{2} \bigg)^2$$
$$SA=4 \pi \bigg( \frac{d^2}{4} \bigg)$$
$$SA=\pi d^2$$

Now you can take the derivative with respect to time.

$$\frac{dSA}{dt}=2 \pi d \frac{dd}{dt}$$

Now just plug in the given information and solve for $\frac{dd}{dt}$.

$$-3=2 \pi (8) \cdot \frac{dd}{dt}$$
$$\frac{-3}{16 \pi}=\frac{dd}{dt}$$

So the diameter is decreasing at a rate of $\frac{3}{16 \pi}$.

Here's a good website that explains this problem in a bit more detail.  The numbers are different, but the process is identical.

https://jakesmathlessons.com/derivatives/related-rates-sphere-surface-area-problem/