# related rate problem of a sphere.

Tags: calculus

> If a snowball melts so that its surface area decreases at a rate of 1 cm^2/min, find the rate at which the diameter decreases when the diameter is 10 cm.

so Surface area of sphere =   $4\pi \cdot r^2$
$\frac{dA}{dT} = 1cm^2/min$
$r = 5$
$diameter = 10$ so $r = 5$
$\frac{dr}{dt} = ?$

$$A = 4 \pi r^2$$
$$\frac{dA}{dT} = 8 \pi r \cdot r'$$
$$ 1 = 8 \pi \cdot 5 \cdot r'$$
$$ \frac{1}{40\pi} = r'$$
so $$\frac{1}{20\pi} = d'$$

Is this right?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192231/related-rates-question-if-a-snowball-melts-so-that-its-surface-area-decreases-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working and answer seem fine.

There is minor inconsistency of notation, usually we use $t$ for time.